# problem with div with 100% height and padding inside a td with 100% height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

An example of issue is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/yjjRW/1/

inner div because of 100% height and margin/padding is overflowing onto next row.
simple stuff..div inside td needs to be 100%, with some padding and margin.
divs inside all tds in the same row needs to be of same height.
I cannot set explicit height on them because their content is decided at runtime.

I can settle for a jQuery fix to this as well.

Thanks

Comment: You are aware than going 100% on an item, then adding padding adds OVER the 100%?

Comment: yes. I know..but unfortunately dont know how to fix it. I cant give inner divs height < 100% because the code which produces the content of inner divs is being used on loads of pages, in each page with container of god-knows-what-damn-height. The ONLY thing I have control over is create a wrapper around the content of divs!

Comment: `100%` + `padding` issue can be solved by having 2 elements where other one is parent and other one is child element. Parent should have the `100%` width or height ( and other visual stuff like border.. bg color ) and the Child element should have the padding.

Comment: Lollero..cant you plz illustrate this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Found an older example of mine of the 100% problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nrNyU/

Answer (score 1):

Set the padding using percents rather than pixels. So give it a 5% padding for the top and bottom, then set the height to 90%.

http://jsfiddle.net/yjjRW/2/

Comment: %ge is calculated on width..so this will still cause the inner div to flow outside

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 add to a DIV

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Other approach would be use of positioning.

```
td {
  position: relative;
}
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  ....
}
```

Or you can use JS solution which is a bit awkward. After page loads, check offsetHeight of each TD and set it to the its firstChild (nested DIV).

Comment: cant use css3..it needs to support old browsers! and just tried the other one in jsfiddle..does not work

Comment: when I integrate your code into my site's page..for some weird reason..the height of my inner-div is getting calculated as 0!

Comment: I checked in firebug as well..no other style is getting applied to either parent (td) or inner content...only the ones which i took from your example are there

Comment: ok..so I investigated further..the table in which td is contained is not set to 100% height..and my limitation is that I cant touch any code outside the td!

Comment: Can you use CSS class/selector to reach the table?

Comment: I will add whatever class name I want to give to parent element